# Where is the Amazon Developer SHA-1 hash for Android App Store?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

To be able to use Google Maps in an Android app on a non-Amazon device, Amazon says that you must add your Amazon SHA-1 hash to the Google Developers API console.

However, I can't find this SHA-1 hash anywhere in the Amazon Developer portal. Does anyone know where it is, or how I can find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment the only way to get the Amazon SHA-1 for your apps would be to contact Amazon at: https://developer.amazon.com/public/support/contact/contact-us . As long as you have either submitted another app or submitted your current app this will be a quick request for them to take care of.

Comment: Yep, I had to çontact them and they sent me the Amazon SHA-1 by email. Pretty strange.

Comment: I contacted them, kept getting someone called Moses and he tells me to contact AWS to get the SHA1

Answer (score 1):

Part of the way down, this link explains how to find your developer hash.

https://developer.amazon.com/blog/tag/Developer+Portal.html

If you haven't registered your app with Amazon yet:

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/android-fireos

Sign-up for the Google Developers Console and add your signing hash to get an API key to enable Google Maps.  This process is explained here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Comment: Hmm, my "My Account" page does not have that area! Weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the SHA keys from :-

Go to Amazon developer console

1. Select Apps & Services > My Apps.
   Select your app.
2. Go to the Upload Your App File screen.
3. Select Appstore Certificate Hashes.

Answer (score 0):

The SHA1 can be found in the amazon developer console -> your app -> app information -> Appstore Certificate Hashes